# How to remove PES header from video stream

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, mpeg

I have captured video stream from the multimedia device which has H264 format.

I want to remove PES header (i.e. first 14 bytes of the frame). Is it possible to do it by `ffmpeg` or any other tool. I tried searching online but didn't find it. I thought of scripting it out and remove it but don't know frame format completely. I know, I have to learn all format stuffs and I am going through it but I need this immediately. Any suggestion/pointers ?

Comment: Does your stream contain the PES packet header? Do you see startcodes (0x000001)?

Comment: yes my stream contains PES package header and I want to remove it. yes I see start code 0x000001

Comment: I meant PES packet header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg -i [file or url] -codec copy out.264

Comment: @sztamary: is it possible to convert stream from `two slices`(two slice packets) to `one slice`(one slice packet) using ffmpeg ?

Comment: Not without transcoding.

Comment: you mean converting to other format ? that is fine. as far I get transport stream somehow.

Comment: I have been going through ffmpeg related posts but haven't found anything as yet.

Comment: then use the same as above but leave off the -codec copy and set the file name to something.ts

Comment: will give it a try

Comment: And while I have chance to ask, is it possible to convert stream with `one slice packet` to stream with `two slice packets` using ffmpeg ?

Comment: Stack overflow should be used as a question/answer platform. Every question should get it’s own post.

Comment: Yeah, I can describe it better in a question. Let me write it.

Comment: Separate post for the same . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58106400/how-to-convert-captured-video-stream-with-two-slice-packet-to-transport-stream-w