# How to convert captured video stream with two slice packet to transport stream with one slice packet using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, transport-stream

I have captured video frame from multi media device. Captured stream has two slice packets. For testing a use case I need to convert it to transport stream with one slice packet.

Any suggestions/pointers?

Answer (score 0):

One slice is default on all h264 encoders I know of. Use ‘ffmpeg -i file.ts our -codec libx264 outfile.ts’

Comment: is it possible to increase slice to two for stream which has one slice packet ? ( I thought I had put this in question don't know what happened)

Comment: Just set the number of slices you want in the x264 opts. It doesn’t matter how many the input has.

Comment: After I modify slice using command `x264 --slices-max 2 input.h264 -o out.h264` and try to play out.h264 in VCL that file doesn't play and VLC throws `mmco: unref short failure` `co located POCs unavailable`.  :(